# In material-react-table, how do I reduce the padding in the table cells?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, material-react-table

I want to modify the padding value in the table cells, which have class names like: `MuiTableCell-root MuiTableCell-body MuiTableCell-sizeMedium css-ny9njj-MuiTableCell-root`

I'm using `material-react-table` v1.14.0. Not finding anything in the documentation about modifying table padding.

Answer (score 1):

Ok looks like adding the following prop to `<MaterialReactTable />` lets you modify the padding of the table cells:

```
<MaterialReactTable
  ...
  muiTableBodyCellProps={{
    sx: {
      paddingTop: 0,
      paddingBottom: 0,
    },
  }}
/>
```